# Would a Ring of Wizardry combined with the Alternative Spell Source Feat allow a Diving Caster to increase prepared spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, magic, cleric

A Ring of Wizardry allows the wearer to double the number of Arcane spell slots per day for the appropriate level.

Alternative Spell Source (Dragon #325) allows characters with this Feat to prepare Divine Spells as Arcane Spells and vice versa, at CL-1.

Would someone with Alternative Spell Source be able to double their Cleric spells of the appropriate level by preparing them as Arcane spells?

If so, could a Good Cleric still Spontaneously cast these slots as healing spells -- Spontaneous Casting states that the Cleric can "lose" any prepared spell that is not a Domain spell to cast a curative spell due to their proficiency with Positive energy. Would a spell such as Protection vs. Evil still be positive energy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ring doubles your Arcane spell slots for the given spell level.

The Feat allows you to prepare Divine spells in your Arcane slots and to prepare Arcane spells in your Divine slots.

It doesn't actually turn your Divine spells into Arcane slots, so they are not doubled.

If you are asking if you can used the doubled Arcane slots to prepare Divine spells, then yes you could.  And going by your wording of casting the curative spells, I believe you could use the Divine spells in the Arcane slots to do so.

Comment: " The wearer’s arcane spells per day are doubled for one specific spell level." Yes, I can see that as a valid interpretation. Divine Spells per day prepared as Arcane are still Divine spell slots per day.

Comment: Correct.   I'll modify the opening sentence.